# curl_multi_exec: Passing null to parameter $still_running of type int is deprecated - why only on some environments?

Tags: php, debugging, curl

We are using https://github.com/ezimuel/ringphp in a Magento 2 package (elasticsuite) which was working fine on our CI (PHP 8.1.7, Ubuntu docker container).

Now on staging, we are getting deprecation warnings.

https://github.com/ezimuel/ringphp/blob/1c444ad129861e70dc0fb00a2b9ed7f1d7c4b953/src/Client/CurlMultiHandler.php#L133

We can reproduce this with the n98-magerun2 dev console:

n98-magerun2 dev:con

```
>>> $foo = curl_multi_init(); $still_running = null; curl_multi_exec($foo, 
$still_running);
PHP Deprecated:  curl_multi_exec(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($still_running) of 
type int is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/n98-magerun2eval()'d code on line 3
>>> echo error_reporting();
32767⏎
```

Error reporting is the same on both machines - why does this sometimes break and sometimes work flawlessly ? What else can be different?

Workaround for the problem itself seems

```
if ($this->active === null) $this->active = 0;
```

above that line.

https://github.com/ezimuel/ringphp/pull/6

Comment: As you probably already know it's because of new relic.

Answer (score 1):

you're not alone, it seems this issue is related to newrelic..

it's has been fixed in this pull request :
https://github.com/ezimuel/ringphp/pull/6/commits/0b6c73b88b869bd8c2591213f54abbf0f7cdea37

you can applied it has follow :

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

add this to your composer.json:

```
 "extra": {
    "patches": {
      "ezimuel/ringphp": {
        "Fix: PHP 8.1 deprecation warning": "https://github.com/ezimuel/ringphp/pull/6/commits/0b6c73b88b869bd8c2591213f54abbf0f7cdea37.patch"
      }
    }
  }
```